How can i activate AT Command in wsl
I HAVE PROPLEM IN WSL < AFTER I WROTE CODE ITS CANT GIVE ME COMMAND AT
and its give not found, need some help.
iam testing my code and be alright is the proplem in driver or my code
#!/bin/bash

# Define the serial device (update with your device name)
SERIAL_DEVICE=/dev/ttyUSB0  # Adjust based on your device

# Open the serial device
exec 3<> $SERIAL_DEVICE

# Send AT commands
echo -e "AT\r" >&3
sleep 1
echo -e "ATI\r" >&3  # Example command to get modem information
sleep 1

# Read response
cat <&3

# Close the serial device
exec 3>&-
exec 3<&-


Does this answer your question? I need help connecting serial ports to Ubuntu in WSL There's no AT command to activate; the thing is that your serial device is not connected to the VM WSL is running in.
